# Fonte com qualidade baixa no html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
body{
    background: url('imagens/capa.png');
    font-family: "Avantgarde", "TeX Gyre Adventor", "URW Gothic L", sans-serif;
}

.texto-capa{
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Tenho essas configurações, porém, independente da fonte que eu colocar, ela sempre fica com qualidade baixa, despixealizada, conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma maneira de reduzir esses "ruidos"?

Comment: Tem estas tambem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76972/70 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9064/70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar algumas técnicas e classes novas do CSS3

Primeiro vou começar com a técnica do `Filter:Blur()`, pelo fato de ninguém ter mencionando ainda. *(Não funciona no IE apenas Edge)*

Aqui estão os resultados com o Filtro. Parece que algumas `font-family`tem um resultado melhor ou pior, cabe a você avaliar se é a melhor técnica.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare no **"e"** no **"t"** e no **"u"** minúsculo como é nítido o resultado 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais um exemplo com e sem o filtro em uma fonte com péssima renderização. ***O filter está no limite, ai vai do bom senso.***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os estilos de filtro precisam de *aceleração de hardwares*, mas parece que mesmo com o *Blur* acentuado consome muito pouco recurso na hora do render e o FPS é praticamente igual, no Chrome pelo menos...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para que quiser fazer uns testes aqui está o Snipper do teste que fiz com `filter:blur()`

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 4.25rem;
    font-family: cursive;
    filter: blur(0.35px);
}
h1:nth-child(1) {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
h1:nth-child(2){
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
h1:nth-child(3){
    font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<h1>Texto Blur1</h1>
<h1>Texto Blur2</h1>
<h1>Texto Blur3</h1>
<h1>Texto Blur4</h1>
```

---

**Técnicas já citadas e conhecidas.**

Você pode colocar um `text-shadow` muito suave, apenas para fazer um efeito de Smooth na font. Veja abaixo no caso coloquei na cor branca que é a cor da sua font.

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.004);
```

O mesmo principio pode ser usado com `-webkit-text-stroke` para todos os Browsers

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.45px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
```

Fonte de referência: https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-text-stroke

Também é possível usar algumas classes CSS

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;  /* não funciona no IE e Edge */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* apenas para Mac OS X/macOS */
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; /* apenas para Mac OS X/macOS */
font-smooth: always; /* Non-standard */
```

**optimizeLegibility:**
O navegador prioriza legibilidade sobre a velocidade de renderização e precisão geométrica. Essa propriedade habilita o kerning e ligatures opcionais.

**font-smoothing *(Non-standard)*:** Aplica um anti-aliasing no contorno da fonte

*Fonte para vc dar uma pesquisada:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering

**Font-smoothing:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

Comment: essa propriedade não conhecia font-smoothing:

Answer (score 0):

Existe no css a propriedade text-rendering:

```
body {
   background: url('imagens/capa.png');
   font-family: "Avantgarde", "TeX Gyre Adventor", "URW Gothic L", sans-serif;
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
     }
```

Se resolver deixa nos comentários se te ajudou.

Veja mais nesse link:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering